# How can I break a loop which has a condition in it? (PHP)

Tags: php, loops, break

I need to break a loop which has a condition inside it, on any circumstance which the condition meets the exception

like this:

```
for($l=0; $l<$subject_count; $l++){
    for($a=0; $a<$term_relatives_id_array_count; $a++){
        if($subject_array[$l]['id'] == $term_relatives_id_array[$a]['subject_id']){
            $subject_echo = true;
            break;
        }
        echo 'a';
    }
    if(!$subject_echo){
        echo '<li class="selectable_item" id="'.$subject_array[$l['id'].'">'.$subject_array[$l]['name_fa'];
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
```

I used `echo 'a';` to see if `break;` works, but it doesn't break the inside loop
what can I do?

Comment: If your `if` condition is met then it will break out of the inner for loop and your echo will not be hit. Subsequently your `li`s will not be printed either.

Comment: exactly! I want it that way, but it won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure.**

So in your case, check if you want to end the execution for both for loops, use `break 2;`

For more reference, refer [break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

And it may be that if condition is not met,so break may not be executed. So check the values also.

Answer (score 1):

Use `break 1;` to exit the current loop and `break 2;` out of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to break both the inner **and** outer loops? In this case you should use `break 2;`

Answer (score 0):

> break accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many nested enclosing structures are to be broken out of.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Example took from the above link:

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
while (++$i) {
    switch ($i) {
    case 5:
        echo "At 5<br />\n";
        break 1;  /* Exit only the switch. */
    case 10:
        echo "At 10; quitting<br />\n";
        break 2;  /* Exit the switch and the while. */
    default:
        break;
    }
}
?>
```