# How do I stop recursion in depth search PHP?

Tags: php, recursion

In this function  that I use to search some element in a tree ,how can I stop the recursion when I found the seached element?

```
public function find($element, $found_path){
    var_dump($element->getName());
    if($element->getAbsolute_path() == $found_path){
        $this->current = &$element;
    } else {
        if(isset($element->descendants)){
            foreach($element->descendants as $descendant){
                $this->find($descendant, $found_path);
            }
        }
    }                   
}
```

The search is correct, but the complete tree is visited. I need to stop when the searched element is found.

Comment: set a flag and then check it in the function every time.

Comment: Use the return keyword to leave the function.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I used `return $element;` instead of `$this->current = &$element;` but the recursion continues

Comment: It would be better to use the returned value of the function for both the result and the recursion stop, with updating a variable there is always the risk it is overwritten by a concurrent fonction execution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: Returning from a recursive array searching function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280124/php-returning-from-a-recursive-array-searching-function)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I break a loop which has a condition in it? (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475470/how-can-i-break-a-loop-which-has-a-condition-in-it-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the `return` or `break` function to escape a loop. For example:

```php
public function find($element, $found_path){
    var_dump($element->getName());
    if($element->getAbsolute_path() == $found_path){
        $this->current = &$element;
    } else {
        if(isset($element->descendants)){
            foreach($element->descendants as $descendant){
                $this->find($descendant, $found_path);
                return;
            }
        }
    }                   
}
```

[Break Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

[Return Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)